# How to build cups generic RPM on OpenSUSE 13.x?

Tags: compile, rpm, cups, rpmbuild, opensuse-13.1

The [cups website](http://www.cups.org/software.php#RPM) suggest to build generic RPM packages with `rpmbuild -ta tarball.tar.gz`, but there's no `dbus-devel` and no `libusb-devel` package in OpenSUSE 13.1 (there's `dbus-1-devel`). Is there a way to satisfy the dependencies of `rpmbuild` easily? I'm trying to build `cups` 2.0.1 on OpenSUSE 13.1 x86_64. Is there another way to build the RPM which is comparable in ease to the use of `rpmbuild`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the `.spec` file from the tar ball, edit the build dependency, and then use

```
rpmbuild -ba cups.spec
```

instead of

```
rpmbuild -ta cups*.tar.gz
```

Comment: Great, thanks. `gcc-c++` needs to be installed manually in `yast2`, because `configure` succeeds even when `g++` is missing.